# react native component passed as props cannot access props?

Tags: react-native

In my understandings React Native components have two ways to be rendered

・passing inside parents tag

・passing as parents'(?) props

For example I have this FlatList component

```
<FlatList
      ListHeaderComponent={MiddleRightLabelComponent}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={SeparatorComponent}
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      keyExtractor={item => item.title}
      // renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      style={styles.flatlist}
      {...this.props}
/>
_renderItem({ item, index }) {
    console.warn(this.props);
    return (
      <ListItem
        id={item.id}
        // onPressItem={this.props.openEditTaskModal.bind(this, true)}
        // selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item.id)}
        title={item.title}
      />
    );
}
```

In this _renderItem console.warn, I get (undefined) when I try to get (this.props).

I need to pass props into ListItem component.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`_renderItem` is creating its own instance of `this`. In stateless components (or functions not bound to component class) you want to refer to the function params directy

```
const _renderItem = (props) => {
    console.warn(props);
    return (
      <ListItem
        id={props.item.id}
        title={props.item.title}
      />
    );
}
```

OR (with es6 destructuring):

```
const _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    console.warn(item);
    return (
      <ListItem
        id={item.id}
        title={item.title}
      />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So how do you pass functions to the stateless components via props?

Comment: same way :D... `props.invokeFunc()`

Comment: Ah thanks... I finally understand how to pass props correctly